# Highcharts x-axis datetime issue

Tags: javascript, datetime, highcharts

in my javascript I defined how to populate a `LineChart` of `Highcharts`. This is populated with the data given by a database. The x-axis of the chart is of `datetime` type and the x-value is `DateTime` type.

```
xAxis: {
     type: 'datetime',
     labels: {
            formatter: function () {
               return Highcharts.dateFormat('%d %b - %H:%M:%S', this.value);
            }
     }
},


lineCharts[index].series[roiIndex].addPoint([point.creationDateTime, point.result]);
```

but what I see is the following:

[image: chart]

I can't find the solution..does anyone have an idea? Thanks!

**EDIT**

Now creationDateTime is the epoch time expressed in milliseconds:

```
DateTime date = roi.created_at;
var epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var creationDateTimeEpoch = Convert.ToInt64((date - epoch).TotalMilliseconds);
```

infact, the value is [image: this one] that converted with https://www.epochconverter.com/ corresponds to the correct value. But now I see the series [image: in this way].

Comment: what is data coming from database can you post it

Comment: `point.creationDateTime` should be a number (timestamp), not a `DateTime` type. If you could also describe what exactly is wrong that would be great :)

Comment: ^that is what is causing your problem. Your `x` values are not in the format Highcharts is looking for, so when you format the values as dates, they process as `0`, which in epoch time translates as the Jan 1 1970 that you are seeing in your labels. You need to send your x value as epoch time, in milliseconds. Ref: https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: For example, the x value is a DateTime as {26/04/2017 11:37:49} but I see 01 Jan 00:00:00. I tried to convert the DateTime to UTC but still not the right date is visualized.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, *x value must be epoch time, in milliseconds*. My final error was that they were all the same, so I saw the vertical lines.