# Highchart X-Axis Label DateTime Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

**My Requirement**

I need to plot a multi series graph - Value vs DateTime(x axis).

**What have I done now**

I get the data from the backend , manipulate the series accordingly and plot the HighChart.

**Update**

My code below:

```
for (i = 0; i < signals.DeviceSignalDataGroupList.length; i++) {
        ddd[i] = [];
        var DeviceSignalModel = signals.DeviceSignalDataGroupList[i];
        name.push(DeviceSignalModel[0].SignalName);
        $.each(DeviceSignalModel, function () {

            ddd[i].push([(new Date(parseInt((this.SignalData.TimeReceived).replace('/Date(', '')))).toLocaleString(), parseInt(this.SignalData.Value)]);  //<=======(LINE A)
            //ddd[i].push([(this.SignalData.TimeReceived).replace('/Date(', '').replace(')/', ''), parseInt(this.SignalData.Value)]); 
        });

        ddd[i] = ddd[i].reverse();
    }
```

The datetime value(`this.SignalData.TimeReceived`) I get from the back end is like `"/Date(1528387441000)/"`
In the above code (where I have marked as LINE A) I replace them and convert to new Date as ToLocaleString().

1. Is that right?
2. Without this conversion too I have tried it doesn't give the expected x-axis date label
3. @ewolden Should I include `.getTime()` there as per your suggestion?

This data in a variable `ddd` has the value something as below:

[image: Data_Sample_Hard_Coded]

***Screenshot for the data coming in from back end***
    [image: Image_showing_Data_from_Back_end_for_3_series]

**My Problem**

The X-Axis Label does not display the correct date format.The screenshot below shows the graph with incorrect value at x-axis. 
What is the wrong am doing here? I am seeing the same issue as mine in 
    [High-charts_x-axis datetime issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43736087/highcharts-x-axis-datetime-issue) but couldn't get an answer from there too.
    [image: graph]

Comment: As the answer from the other question you referenced says, time needs to be in in milliseconds since 1970. That is the timeformat highcharts understands.

Comment: But with that change , the graph lines becomes vertical is what the updated answers says. ___If you still suggest me  that please let me how should I change my data value.

Comment: The answer says, that it was because the person used the same timestamp for all values, but it got fixed once they fixed that. You need to convert like this: `new Date(ddd[2][j).getTime()` where j is a new for loop over all the elements in ddd[2], i.e. your time.

Comment: I just saw your picture with code, (please embed the code, and don't use a picture, it makes it a lot easier for people trying to help), and you just need to use `getTime()` on the `Date` object. And then set `type: 'datetime'` on the xAxis.

Comment: Oh Ok sure Actually with code embedded I wasn't able to *Post Question`* , t'was giving error message not well formatted code, so I included them as a picture. __Now I placed a part of my code there. Also I have updated my question please let me know on my queries included now in the updated section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to format time to be in milliseconds, that entails two things, one set type `datetime`:

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  ...
}
```

And fix the function getting the timestamps, like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < signals.DeviceSignalDataGroupList.length; i++) {
  ddd[i] = [];
  var DeviceSignalModel = signals.DeviceSignalDataGroupList[i];
  name.push(DeviceSignalModel[0].SignalName);

  $.each(DeviceSignalModel, function () {
    ddd[i].push([(new Date(parseInt((this.SignalData.TimeReceived).replace('/Date(', '')))).getTime(), parseInt(this.SignalData.Value)]);  // changed toLocaleString() to getTime()
  });

  ddd[i] = ddd[i].reverse();
}
```